# Elastic Search sort documents with same score using another field value

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search and I would like to sort documents having same score to the query shown below, on the basis of higher number of - "likes" field - integer type stored in all documents. Code -

```
query: {
                multi_match: {
                        query: "some cooler",
                        type: "most_fields",
                        fields: ["info1", "info2", "info3"]
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check the [sort documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

Just add a sort section on json sorting by score followed by your custom field.

```
{
    "query" : {...},
    "sort" : [
        "_score",
        { "likes" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ]
}
```

score order is 'desc' by default. Other fields are 'asc' by default so you need to define 'desc' order for your 'likes' field if that's what you want.